# Jenkins GitHub plugin is caching an old SCM host

Tags: jenkins, github-api, bitbucket-api

So, we've migrated from bitbucket to github.
Some projects are working with `GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling.` therefore they're being able to listen for changes when a push happens.

But, there are some projects in which we're getting this message.

```
The webhook for repo ORGANIZATION/REPO_NAME on bitbucket.org failed to be registered or was removed. 
More info can be found on the global configuration page.
This message will be dismissed if Jenkins receives a PING event from repo webhook or if you add the repo to the ignore list in the global configuration.
```

We already tried to set the cache to 0 and also removed the cache in /var/lib/jenkins/caches , but still we were not able to get it working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In the end we ended up creating new pipelines based on the pipelines that were already working...